# Online HTML/CSS/Javascript learning reference alternative to w3schools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reference

From my time on SO I've found w3schools may not be the best place to send people as an html/web programming reference.  I started using them a loooong time ago and have been sending people there for years because of their usage of programming categories and tutorials.

I know I can go there and easily find out what different tags are available for use(though it may not be correct) and I can find out attributes to tags easily.  Are there any alternatives that can provide the same simple reference and tutorials as they do?  Where should I refer people too?

Comment: W3Schools is not a bad site. I mean, their tuturials are not bad. As long as you don't get fooled into thinking they have any official status whatsoever. For instance, those certificates of theirs mean absolutely nothing. The only real complaint I have about W3Schools is they pretend that what they have is all there is, all you need. Other than that, their content isn't much worse than what other sites have.

Comment: There are lots of free lessons on HTML5, JavaScript, and jQuery from DevelopMentor in their online courses at LearningLine: 

https://learninglineapp.com/schedule.

Comment: See http://www.w3fools.com/ for a good description.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- [blooberry.com](http://blooberry.com)
- MSDN ([HTML & CSS section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa737439.aspx))
- [HTML 4.01 Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)
- [WHATWG's HTML 5 Reference](http://whatwg.org/html5)

[W3Fools - A W3Schools Intervention](http://w3fools.com/) also promotes the following "more reputable sources":

> [Opera Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc) covers the basics of web standards-based design in HTML and CSS.
>   [Google's HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/) presents the basics of web development with video tutorials presented by Google's expert web developers.
>   [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/) is a pretty good reference for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Their documentation always mentions feature support across different browsers, and describes known browser bugs.
>   The W3C, itself, has a wiki-based general [Learn](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Learn) page as well as an [HTML element reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements).
>   [The MDN (Mozilla's Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) takes over at intermediate CSS and covers JavaScript better than anyone.
>   The MDN is also a wiki (little known fact), which means we, as knowledgeable web developers, can add or change information so the pages are as effective and comprehensive as possible.

Comment: That looks like an excellent reference guide I've never seen before.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Looks like Google Doctype is down...

Comment: Google Doctype is marked as "No Longer Available" (and it's actually down from October 2011).

Comment: http://www.snoopcode.com is a great alternative for w3schools. Please add that to the list.

Answer (score 10):

In general, my first stop for HTML, Javascript or DOM information is the [MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) from the Mozilla Developer Network.  It is occasionally Firefox/Gecko-specific, but is in general a good first stop.

- [HTML doc center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/)
- [Javascript doc center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript)
- [DOM doc center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM)

Personally, I find the HTML spec (and even more the DOM spec) far to hard to take in quickly or to use as a quick reference. MDC is great for that.

Comment: I've only recently heard about the MDC.  I didn't realize they had tutorials/etc getting people familiar with HTMl.  Great suggestion

Answer (score 3):

There are too many good references out there, but these are my two cents. Hope it helps:

- Great tricks, references and
  examples:
  http://www.quirksmode.org/sitemap.html
- Nice step by step:
  http://nearlythere.com/mite03/css-tutorial/
- Cheat sheets (pretty cool!!):
  http://sixrevisions.com/resources/cheat_sheets_web_developer/

Comment: `nearlythere` link is broken

Comment: Yep, it worked a year ago, :D.
Today I'd rather stay with codeacademy courses for any step by step learning process. Check it out: http://www.codecademy.com/es/tracks/htmlcss, http://www.codecademy.com/es/tracks/javascript-combined

Answer (score 2):

The **very best** HTML reference is the HTML spec itself:

- [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)
- [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html)

It provides examples of how elements/attributes can be used, and the expected reactions in many case situations.

Comment: The w3 specs can be pretty intimidating to new web programmers.  I'm looking for more of a simplified learning reference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: jump down the index to the html element you're after, skip the intro. It's not a book, it's a reference.

Comment: I down-voted because IMHO Definitely not for learning! Excellent, yes, but not for beginners!

Comment: this is the problem - people think the w3 specs are the answer

Comment: @byronyasgur, have you read the HTML5 spec? it's not hard to read and has good examples. I learned more about HTML out of reading the specs than any other resource.

Comment: yes of course, but the trouble is a completely different tool which is required - w3 specs should be used for what they are designed for - specifications - this not a reference - I think of it as a pyramid with the specs at the base - the reference above that - cheat sheets and snipits above that and our brains/memory above that  ..... you cant seriously expect newbie students to get deep into the specs in the middle of trying to work out a problem/project. I've been using html for 12 years and it takes me ages to get through the specs ( which necessarily cover ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING )...my 10c

Comment: @byronyasgur, I can and *will* expect newbie students to use `CTRL+F` to search the spec for what they need. I regularly search the spec for references. I don't want to get into a debate, but it doesn't take very long to scan for details, such as what attributes are required on a particular element.

Comment: @zzzzBov I dont want to get into a debate either so I respect your opinion ( but I will continue to try to understand why people dont see any chasm between the specs and the proverbial "hello world" scenario) ..... but while i concede that the w3 site is obviously a great and accurate resource I think it displays the information not so well ( unless you're a developer building a browser or something )... ctrl-f ing through a page is not good in my opinion. W3schools unfortunately has the perfect layout which is probably why it's so popular - pity the information on it is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The first place you should probably send somebody for reference would be the most official body of reference for the subject.  For example, if somebody was asking about a particular HTML tag or something about the HTML spec, their first stop should be [that spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) (as an example, and there are lots of page anchors throughout that spec to navigate directly to what the user needs).

Examples can often be quickly found via Google.  If the Google results are clearly plentiful and seem pretty good, then just linking the user to the Google search itself would work fine.  (And may subtly nudge them to use Google a little more thoroughly, though keep in mind that SO generally doesn't want its answers to just be "just Google it" so use tact and offer additional information beyond just the search.)

Answer (score 1):

I love this one:

[I love the opera tutorial.](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/12-the-basics-of-html/) (From there onwards).

Concise but complete and very clearly explained!

[See the table of contents here.](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc)

Answer (score 1):

There is the W3C's [Web Education Community Group Wiki](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/), on standards that are maintained by them. It provides quite some useful information on e.g. HTML and CSS, and they link to appropriate standards.

See for example [this page on the `textarea` element](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea)

**EDIT:** I just realize this was already mentioned as 'general Learn page' from the W3Fools page, but it might still be useful to name this reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like Microsoft's MSDN and Mozilla's MDN are not bad, as long as you remember that they view the world through coloured glasses. The only real reference is, of course, the W3C.
Whenever some site's information clashes with the information on the W3C's site, the W3C is always right.

Keep that in mind and you can safely peruse other websites, even W3Schools. W3Schools is not better or worse than other non-official websites.