# Using div as alternative to iframe

Tags: php, iframe, html

I have an iframe on my site that shows the full contents of an external site. I want to get rid of the iframe but keep the same functionality. I was thinking of using a div with `overflow=auto`. Problem is, when I attempt to include an external site using php, such as `include 'http://www.site.com';` or `echo file_get_contents("http://www.site.com");`, the site shows up but it takes over formatting, the site's name appears in the titlebar, etc. How might I replace the iframe functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> How might I replace the iframe functionality?

This is **not** easily possible. You run into the problems you just described and to solve those is a real hard job. I don't know of an existing component that does this.

Instead stick to the iframe. What's so bad about it?

Comment: The external site won't load in an iframe. It's header denies it.

Comment: The site is probably using an iframe buster. You might want to look at one of [Jeff Atwood's questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed).

Comment: How about using another page to load the external page and then showing that page in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting rid of the iframe because of its default ugly border then you can just make the iframe look seamless using the 'seamless' attribute of iframe

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_seamless.asp

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer: Thanks a lot! never knew about this! what do you think is the better source to learn web technologies apart from w3schools?

Comment: There are lots of alternatives. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662304/online-html-css-javascript-learning-reference-alternative-to-w3schools) provides some. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is also a good reference.