# Contact page error with PHP

Tags: php

I have a contact page and I am having trouble with the php reading the Name* field as the 5 characters because I am saving space on my webpage by putting the Name* inside the text area to begin with.  I have researched on google and I can't find any code to help ignore those characters.  The php I have is posted below.

```
if(!$name || strlen($name) < 5) {
    $error .= "Please enter your name.<br />";
}
```

So the problem I am running into is well maybe someone has a 3 letter name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tip: Don't. Use a real label, don't just dump the default text in the textbox. Besides, how does it save space?

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="Name*" />
Name*: <input type="text" name="name" />
```

Doesn't make sense.

---

If you must, just add `|| $name == "Name*"` in there.

Comment: Using a real label would mean: `<label for="name">Name:</label>` - but yeah I do agree, that would be the best option. Who cares about the extra 50 characters, it becomes 100x more user friendly. +1

Comment: I assume the OP meant it "saves space" in that the label text occupies the input itself. It saves space in the rendered page, not the HTML source.

Comment: @Wesley yes this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Kolink I went with the if statement you gave me in my php.  Thank you so much it works as I need it to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name*" />
```

This is not supported across most browsers except the older versions of IE - http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Better reference site - http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder (thnx Celeritas)

Comment: The advantage of this is it will work on `password` fields too. Where other methods are not going to (they will show ******)

Comment: -1 for referencing w3schools. Support for it really isn't that great. http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Comment: Thanks Celeritas. I was trying to find a good reference site. So current browser versions all support it - except for IE and Opera Mini. FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari all have supported it for 4 verisons... seems like its fine for support. Oh and Android and iOS support it too =)

Comment: Right, according to them that's about 40% of web browsers who can't use it. Also it's part of HTML 5 which is not yet finalized. Please do try to avoid w3cschools whenever possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662304/online-html-css-javascript-learning-reference-alternative-to-w3schools and http://mmitpros.ning.com/forum/topics/why-you-should-not-use

Comment: Thanks that's better. Just one more thing I think he wants the text "Name*" with the astrix on the end so I think you meant to have `placeholder="Name*"`

Comment: Yeah I know that isn't the best site. The question is how can he achieve what he needs - even though support for this feature is not quite ubiquitous yet... it does what he needs, and doesn't involve server side manipulation, or JS hacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it to save layout space, you can try something like this to clear the default value in the field when you focus the field.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'value') { this.value = ''; }" value="value" />
```

Comment: What if the field is not focused? `onsubmit` on the form would make more sense, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to skip the first 5 characters.

Assuming your using POST to pass the form data

```
$name = substr($POST['name'], 5)
```

Kolink is right, I don't see how this saves space, just right Name* outside of the textbox. If you really want to keep it inside the box you could use JavaScript to clear the box when it's clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

As Kolink said, you can add `|| $name == "Name*"` to your `if` statement.

Otherwise, this is more of a client side issue. If you are using JQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#name').attr("is_focused",0);
$('#name').focus(function(){
    if($(this).attr("is_focused")==0){
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("is_focused",1);
    }
});
```

Then when the user submits the form do this check:

```
if($('#name').attr("is_focused")==0){
    alert('You must enter your name');
    return;
}
```